# 22.04 can't input password for wifi

Tags: wireless

I'm unable to connect to a wifi on Ubuntu 22.04. Every time I click any of the wifi SSIDs it briefly, and I mean very briefly, pops up what looks like an authentication required window where I could put in a password before disappearing. This window is up and gone in the blink of an eye.

Suggestions?

Comment: I have the exact same issue. wifi a a whole has been shoddy on 22.04 pre-updates the adapter isn't even detected.

Answer (score 3):

Wow, so I have a solution to a problem for the first time! It doesn't change the fact that there's a bug in the system, but there's a much better workaround that you can do.

Open your WiFi settings, and at the top, click on the 3 dots (the poor, graphical version of a "more option" menu).

Then select "Connect to Hidden Network"

From here, you have to select "new" connection from the dropdown and input the network name despite the fact that you will already be able to see the chosen network.

Finally, select the type of encryption your WiFi network is using, and you can input the password here.

It's not ideal. It's a pretty major bug. But this is an easy way to use the existing systems to connect to any network.

Comment: what's the type of encryption you selected? I have no clue what is standard here. (I ask because I don't give a damn about per-user case. I know that 99% of routers use the same I just don't want to have to try each one until it works)

Comment: for those who get here it's "WPA & WPA2 Personal" thanks for your answer this worked for me!

Comment: Thanks I had the same issue. When I restart the system it's fine but this gives me a way to not restart!

Answer (score 1):

This is mildly unsatisfying work around, but I was hit the same problem and was able to connect via the command line as described here:

https://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-22-04-connect-to-wifi-from-command-line

On Ubuntu 22.04 on my laptop, I had to change this file

```
$ cat /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
```

This was my configuration.  Note that iliadbo2 is the ESSID, and fake_password is the password.

```
network:
   version: 2
   renderer: NetworkManager
   wifis:
      wlp0s20f3:
        optional: true
        access-points:
            "iliadbo2":
                password: "fake_password"
        dhcp4: true
```

After I editted the file, I ran

```
sudo netplan apply
```

Answer (score 1):

I found another answer [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/uxp3q6/whenever_i_try_to_connect_new_wifi_the_password/):  Steam is running (i.e. the Steam menu is visible in the topbar).  For some unknown reason the Steam app induces this weird behavior in the wifi password dialog.  (Makes me wonder what Steam is doing that causes this...)

Exiting Steam fixed the problem for me.

Comment: This! I quit Steam, and suddenly it worked again! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Load the password into the clipboard (type it somewhere and copy it), then paste it into the dialog during the brief time it's up.

Comment: Given that the OP says that the it "is up and gone in the blink of an eye" I suspect they won't have time to paste and click connect. But maybe helpful for someone else.