I can't connect to wifi because the system doesn't ask a password
I'm running Lubuntu 22.04.4 LTS on a old laptop. Everything works fine, except for this problem: with certain routers (luckily at home everything works fine, but sadly not at university)  when I click on their names I don't get the pop up which asks for the password, therefore I'm unable to connect. How can I solve this problem? I need it in order to study at uni
I tried to click on different SSIDs and on certain the pop up appears (on a printer and on other random SSID), sadly for other doesn't.
Neofetch results:
OS: Lubuntu 22.04.4 LTS x86_64   
Host: VPCEB1A4E C6041PF9         
Kernel: 6.5.0-35-generic         
Uptime: 1 hour, 4 mins           
Packages: 1810 (dpkg), 8 (snap)  
Shell: bash 5.1.16               
Resolution: 1366x768             
DE: LXQt 0.17.1                  
WM: Openbox                      
Theme: Arc-Darker [GTK3]         
Icons: Adwaita [GTK3]            
Terminal: qterminal              
Terminal Font: Ubuntu Mono 14    
CPU: Intel i3 M 330 (4) @ 2.133G 
GPU: AMD ATI Mobility Radeon HD  
Memory: 2127MiB / 3762MiB


Contact the University IT the issue is their setup.

Have you tried to go into Settings -> Wi-Fi -> Saved Wi-Fi Networks. If the connection is remembered there is a rubbish-bin symbol (Forget Network). Try to connect to network again.

I've contacted the University IT (I have to specify that I'm trying to connect to a different University) and they have said that I have to connect at my University first, than I can try in this different one (they use the same shared system, Eduroam)

There isn't a saved connection, because it's a fresh install and I have connected only to my house's wifi.
I have tried this method (https://askubuntu.com/a/1429777/1758888) but sadly didn't work
p.s. I'm sorry for my mistakes in the original post.

You mentioned Eduroam, so I looked it up and found in their FAQ that they use security certificates. So you need to talk to your home University IT department and get their certificate. You'll also need to figure out all the details to configure your connection: security method (probably Dynamic WEP/802.1x), authentication method (possibly PEAP), identity, domain, etc. Then you can go to Preferences → Advanced Network Configuration and click the plus sign and set up the connection accordingly.

This page contains information on connecting to Eduroam on Ubuntu. They don't use a password; they use WPA2-enterprise. Details may be different for your university. It's up to the home institution what authentication to use.
